# jQuery - Get the attribute of multiple elements and match it to other elements' ids?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-waypoints

How can I get jQuery to compare an `id` to an attribute and if matching add an `.active`class to the element with the matching attribute?

I'm trying to refactor a long and repetitive jQuery code. I have set waypoints to trigger on scroll, once you reach a certain section it adds an active class to the menu link that refers to the section. This is the best I could manage, but it is not working.

```
$('section').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active-nav');
    var linkName = $('nav a').map( function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
    }).get();
    if(linkName == $('section[id]')){
         $(this).addClass('active-nav');
        }
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
```

The thinking behind this is that my section `id` is the same as the `href`value of the menu link (it's an anchor bookmark), so my logic is: Compare the`section id`to the `nav a href` value, and if they match `addClass .active` to this menu link. How can I achieve this logic?

a- How do I get the `href`of all the links in `nav`?

b- How do I then compare it to the `section id` and`addClass`to the nav link that matches?

my html looks something like this:

```
<nav>
 <a id="b1" href="#landing">Home</a>
 <a id="b2" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
 <a id="b3" href="#experience">Experience</a>
 <a id="b4" href="#about">About</a>
</nav>

<section id="landing">some content</section>
<section id="portfolio">some content</section>
<section id="experience">some content</section>
<section id="about">some content</section>
```

And my current jQuery looks like this

```
$('#landing').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active-nav');
    $('#b1').addClass('active-nav');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});

$('#landing').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active-nav');
    $('#b1').addClass('active-nav');
  }
}, {
  offset: '-25%'
});
```

Which works just fine but has to be repeated for every section individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `id` of each section and attaching handlers, you can use the `section` selector like this:

```
// this event is called for all sections.
$('section').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active-nav');

    // form the selector dynamically.
    // "this" keyword refers waypoint object and the element is located at "this.element"
    // using "this.element.id", get the nav anchor you want to target
    // example: "nav a[href='#landing']"

    var selector = "nav a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']"; 
    $(selector).addClass('active-nav');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
```

```
$('section').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active-nav');
    var selector = "nav a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']"; 
    $(selector).addClass('active-nav');
  }
}, {
  offset: '-25%'
});
```

There are different ways to get the target element you want. In your case, since the `section` and `a` elements are in the same order, you can use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`eq(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) (**Important:** You need to wrap your sections with a `div` for "`index()`" to work.)

```
// this event is called for all sections.
$('section').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active-nav');
    $("nav a").eq($(this.element).index()).addClass('active-nav');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/mxsjo070/3/) for the second way of doing. Test it and let me know.

Comment: I have tried the first suggestion. Then the last one, but neither of them is adding the `active-nav` class to the nav links. Did I need to do something more before implementing, or was it supposed to work as is?

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? Could be missing quotation while concatinating

Comment: no errors. it just removes the class and then doesn't add.

Comment: @Syknapse I fixed it. Apparently, `this` means waypoint obejct. To get the DOM element we need to refer `this.element`. Updated the answer with a fiddle for second way

Comment: Oh you absolute star! Worked like a charm, straight up. And Messi is the best without a doubt. You have taught me a great lesson. Thanks
And if you need any help with your Spanish hit me up.

Comment: @Syknapse glad it helped you. I wans't aware of `waypoint` up unitl now. So I learned something new too. (Also, please upvote and accept the answer)

Comment: @Syknapse yo aprendo espanol en duolingo. 43% fluency!